# Should one combine foreign keys that point to the same table if all columns are required?

Tags: mysql

I encounter this situation frequently. An example,

A `user` is uniquely identified by `appId, externalUserId`.

Table `xxxContract` has a foreign key `(fileUploadId, appId, externalUserId)` to table `fileUpload` that ensures the file upload belongs to the specified user.

Table `xxxContract` has a foreign key `(businessId, appId, externalUserId)` to table `business` that ensures the business belongs to the specified user.

With the above two, we guarantee user A's file upload won't be used as a contract for user B's business.

---

`xxxContract` also has a `fileTypeId` column that is `STORED GENERATED` to a certain value that says "This contract is of file type `XXX_CONTRACT`"

Table `xxxContract` also has a foreign key `(fileUploadId, fileTypeId)` to table `fileUpload`.

This guarantees we only use `XXX_CONTRACT` file uploads for `xxxContract`, and not accidentally use other file types.

---

Given the above, we have this situation where we have two foreign keys that point to the same table `fileUpload`, and even have overlapping columns,

- `(fileUploadId, appId, externalUserId)`
- `(fileUploadId, fileTypeId)`

And all the columns are `NOT NULL`.

So, it seems to me like it's safe to combine the foreign keys into one larger foreign key,

`(fileUploadId, appId, externalUserId, fileTypeId)`

And we'll still have the same guarantees as before.

---

My gut feeling is that I *should not* combine the foreign keys because separating them by meaning and giving the FKs meaningful names helps with maintainability.

But I've never had a formal education with these things so I'd like to know what the industry standard is.

Related, is there a performance benefit to combining them vs. separating them?

Answer (score 0):

> But I've never had a formal education with these things so I'd like to know what the industry standard is.

The standard is, that there is no standard.

As you already noted, you can use multiple columns to define a primary key. This is called a *natural primary key*, for instance: A user can be uniquely identified by firstname, lastname - and birthdate. (at least almost ever)

This kind of keys is often called composite keys, because every column alone doesn't work out, only combined they form a primary key.

Surrogate (or artifical) primary keys are also well known: `id` column, using auto-increment.

So, as to your question: Yes, if you have 3 columns that already form a natural primary key, it is completly safe to add more columns. Since the 3 columns already present will uniquely identify the row, there is no harm in adding a 4th, 5th or even 6th column to the key.

Whether you are going to use natural or surrogate primary keys depens on personal preference i'd say. I never use natural keys, even on tables where this is possible.

Keep in mind, that whenever you need to delete / update something, you always need to know the primary key. hence, with natural keys, you need to move multiple values through many method-calls, while surrogate keys offer the advantage of just having "one" id to uniquely identify a row. No more information required.

Performance-wise, i assume that (Integer-based) surrogate primary keys tend to be faster than (String-based) natural primary keys. It's even less columns to consider when writing queries and/or designing indexes.

Comment: My problem isn't with primary keys. My problem is that I have two foreign keys that ensure a particular row in another table satisfies some business logic. But these two foreign keys could be combined into one foreign key without losing any safety. Should I combine such FKs? Or should I keep them separate for maintainable code?

Comment: Just to be clear, if I wanted to ensure a row in `fileType` exists, I could just use an FK of one column, `(fileTypeId)`. But I want it so that this row must also belong to the same user of a different table, and that this row must also be of a certain "type". So, the two FKs I'm using guarantee these two different requirements.